# FlaskSocket IO getting Data from postgresql up to date

Tags: python, postgresql, socket.io, sqlalchemy, flask-socketio

I am trying to get realtime data from my database made with PostgreSQL in my Flask APP. For that I am trying to use Socket IO, but I am not sure if it is the correct solution and in case it is, I am not sure how to implement it. Anyone could help me?

Thank you,

Jonathan Prieto

This is what i have for the moment:

```
@socketio.on('solicitudes_id')
def broad_consolidado():
    consolidado_data = Consolidado.query.all()
    emit('consolidado', consolidado_data, broadcast=True)

@app.route('/consolidado')
@login_required
def show_consolidado():
    return render_template("consolidado.html")
```

And in the HTML side:

```
<div style="overflow: auto">
 

                <table id="dtHorizontalExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>solicitudes_id</th>
                            <th>id_user</th>
                            <th>tipouso</th>
                            <th>tipoauto</th>
                            <th>credito</th>
                            <th>entidadcrediticia</th>
                            <th>id_auto</th>
                            <th>fecha</th>
                            <th>canalinput</th>
                            <th>ciudadcompra</th>
                            <th>hora</th>
                            <th>nombre</th>
                            <th>appellidos</th>
                            <th>numdocumento</th>
                            <th>numtelefono</th>
                            <th>correo</th>
                            <th>tipolicencia</th>
                            <th>tiempolicencia</th>
                            <th>trabajoaplicativo</th>
                            <th>tipodocumento</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                        <script type="text/javascript">
                              var socket = io.connect('https://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
                              console.log('https://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
                              socket.on( 'consolidado', function( consolidado ) {
                                  for (var i = 0; i < consolidado.length; i++) {
                                        console.log( consolidado[i].solicitudes_id );
                                        $( 'tbody' ).append('<tr> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].solicitudes_id+ '</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].id_user+'</td> <td>' +
                                            consolidado[i].tipouso+ '</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].tipoauto+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].credito+ '</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].entidadcrediticia+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].id_auto+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].fecha+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].canalinput+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].ciudadcompra+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].hora+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].nombre+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].appellidos+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].numdocumento+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].numtelefono+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].correo+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].tipolicencia+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].tiempolicencia+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].trabajoaplicativo+'</td> <td>'+
                                            consolidado[i].tipodocumento+'</td> </tr>')
                                }
                              })
                        </script>

                    </tbody>
 
 
                </table>
            </div>
```

I had some issues with the server-side getting some errors but now everything is ok, no errors but in my website, the table is empty.

Comment: The client never emits the `solicitudes_id` event, as far as I can see. Does this happen somewhere else in the code that you have not shared?

Comment: You are completely right @Miguel , this was my mistake. I added this: ```setInterval(function(){
                                socket.emit('update', 'ejecutar');
                              }, 1000);```

Comment: Did that solve your problem?

Comment: Yes! Now every second, my client emit this message to the backend to have the update table from my database.